# PHP execute all files in a folder

Tags: php, windows

Im working on a PHP script that is executing chosen website projects. (Only on my local computer).

What i would want it to do is execute ALL files it can find in a folder. It would take time to always change the code when i add a, for example, .php file or .css file.

Im using windows 7.

Is it possible somehow?

Code so far:

```
exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\",$output, $return);
```

Comment: Use `glob()` and exec each one. http://php.net/glob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (glob("path/ToFile/*.php") as $filename) {
    exec($filename, $output); // previously $Filename
}
```

Perhaps this might perform the task you require

```
foreach (glob("path/ToFile/*.php") as $filename) {
 echo $filename."<br>";
}
```

See if you are getting any files

Comment: No idea why, but it didnt work. Tried both path from script and from windows harddrive.

Comment: @user2336174 See my update, echo out the `filename` to see if it's correctly populated

Comment: It is, got all the names. This is the error: Warning: exec(): Cannot execute a blank command in, Notice: Undefined variable: Filename i

Comment: I see it too now, haha! Thanks for the help! Appreciate it